Launch a command in every subdirectory and retrieve filename from the subdirectory
I have a bunch of folders and files organized like this:
x (folder)
  x.pdf (file)
y
  y.pdf
...

I would like to launch a command applying to each pdf in subdirectory in a bash script. This command will create new files in each subdirectory with the same name than the pdf + 001, 002, etc.
The command is pdfimages -j x.pdf x. It will creates x-001.jpg, x-002.jpg[...] (as many jpeg than the number of pages in the pdf).
When I am trying solution such as described in Perform an action in every sub-directory using Bash
for D in /*
do
pdfimages -j *.pdf "$(basename "$D")"
done

I always obtain:
I/O Error: Couldn't open file '*.pdf': No such file or directory.
How can I retrieve the name of a file from a subdirectory?

find -execdir will handle this for you. Don't reinvent wheels.

What you need is to change directory:
for D in /*/     # only match dirs
do
(                # start a subshell
    cd "$D" 
    pdfimages -j ./*.pdf "$(basename "$D")"
)
done


Put || exit after the cd to abort the subshell so you don't run commands in the wrong directory if it fails.

Shellcheck also identifies the missing check for a failed cd, and one other potential problem.

Post edited accordingly

How about something like:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob

for f in ./*/*.pdf; do
  echo pdfimages -j "$f" "${f%.pdf}"
done


An example output of the command. Since foo,bar,baz,more,qux are the directories and 1,2,3,4,5 are the *.pdf files.
pdfimages -j ./bar/1.pdf ./bar/1
pdfimages -j ./baz/2.pdf ./baz/2
pdfimages -j ./foo/3.pdf ./foo/3
pdfimages -j ./more/4.pdf ./more/4
pdfimages -j ./qux/5.pdf ./qux/5



Remove the echo if you think the command is correct and to actually convert those *.pdf files.


Why not use find . -name '*.pdf' -execdir pdfimages -j -- {} +?

As far as I know, not all find has -execdir no?

The idea is good, but for the command I suggest pdfimages -j "$f" "${f%.pdf}"

@pjh, right I just realize that basename and dirname is the same as "$f, much obligde.

@CharlesDuffy, https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9799919799/utilities/find.html does dot have -execdir

@CharlesDuffy, a second, "image-root", command line argument is required when running pdfimages, so the suggested find ... -execdir ... command doesn't work in its current form.

@CharlesDuffy, another issue with the suggested find command is that it will not just process .pdf files in immediate subdirectories of the current directory.  Additional options (-mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2) are required to make it do that.

The wildcard *.pdf is being expanded in the current directory, not the subdirectory D. Append the wildcard to the directory
for D in /*
do
    if [ -d "$D" ]
    then
        pdfimages -j "$D"/*.pdf "$(basename "$D")"
    fi
done

